# EmberJs - unable to implement dynamic-import-polyfill

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, polyfills

We are trying to implement dynamic-import-polyfill to import external file Ember compile time(build time).

Followed steps mentioned in https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/dynamic-import-polyfill

but got stuck when adding following lines of code in ember-cli-build.js.

following line of import works fine ,because with this I can successfully bring ember server up

**import dynamicImportPolyfill from 'dynamic-import-polyfill';**

but as soon as I am adding following lines ,ember server throws exception on start and stops

dynamicImportPolyfill.initialize({
    modulePath: '/web-app', // Defaults to '.'
    importFunctionName: '$$$import' // Defaults to '**import**'
  });

When checked in error logs found following error

**stack: ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at Object.e.initialize (C:\code\Project-Chimps\source\web-app\node_modules\dynamic-import-polyfill\dist\dynamic-import-polyfill.umd.js:1:366)**

tried lots of sites but no where I got the proper example:

while defining dynamicImportPolyfill.initialize({....
what should be the value for modulePath:

I did not understand following info mentioned for modulePath

modulePath  string
A path for which all relative import URLs will resolve from.

Default Value: '.'

This should be an absolute path to the directory where your production modules are deployed (e.g. /public/). If given a relative path, it is resolve against the current page's URL.

Someone please help us with the example how I can use  dynamic-import-polyfill  with EmberJs

Comment: Did you had a look at [`ember-auto-import`](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import)?

Comment: Thanks @jelhan ,
I will try ember-auto-import  will post my experience

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add this polyfill for your ember app. [ember-auto-import](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import) already supports this feature after some [additional configuration](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import#dynamic-import). Once you've installed and configured `ember-auto-import` you can dynamically import any NPM package and it will be loaded only when needed.

The step of adding and configuring `ember-auto-import` will be unnecessary very soon as Ember Octane Edition (set to be finalized in November 2019) will include this functionality by default in all apps.

Comment: Thanks @jrjohnson,

 I will try ember-auto-import will post my experience soon